# Restructure a Multi-Level Content Presentation System

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling

I am new to javascript, and I'm developing educational materials for my students at our school in India. I have created this structure that allows for cycling through lists of words with prev/next buttons, changing categories, and the ability to click on any given word to hear it spoken via text-to-speech.

It works and it's the most complicated thing I've been able to do, but I know it has to be horribly inefficient and outdated in the way it's constructed. I'm trying to learn more about event listeners, and how to simplify structures in general. I've spent the last five hours trying to change this structure using what I've learned, but the prev/next nav part and the fact that my items are in an array makes it beyond my scope.

Hopefully it's not out of line to ask for general input about how to reconfigure this to be more economical. I have put a lot of effort into getting this far with my woeful skillset. Many thanks for any assistance. If snippet isn't working page can be seen [here].[1](http://clients.brettcolephotography.com/test)

```js
var levelone = [
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Apple</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Banana</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Grapes</div>",
];
var leveltwo = [
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Dog</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Cat</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Horse</div>",
];
var levelthree = [
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Red</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Yellow</div>",
"<div onclick=\"jQuery(this).articulate('rate',1).articulate('setVoice','language','hi').articulate('speak')\" data-articulate-append=\"\">Blue</div>",
];
            
            var box = document.getElementById('box');
            var i = -1;
            function next() {
                i = i >= start.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
                box.innerHTML = start[i];
            }
            function prev() {
                i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : sav.length - 1;
                box.innerHTML = start[i];
            }
            
            $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
                var nextDiv = $(".step:visible").next(".step");
                if (nextDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to beginning
                    nextDiv = $(".step:first");
                }
                $(".step").hide();
                nextDiv.show();
            });
                                
            $("#prevBtn").click(function() {
                var prevDiv = $(".step:visible").prev(".step");
                if (prevDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to end
                    prevDiv = $(".step:last");
                }
                $(".step").hide();
                prevDiv.show();
            });
            function lone() {
                start = levelone.slice(0);
                box.innerHTML = levelone[0];
            }
            function ltwo() {
                start = leveltwo.slice(0);
                box.innerHTML = leveltwo[0];
            }
            function lthree() {
                start = levelthree.slice(0);
                box.innerHTML = levelthree[0];
            }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px; 
  line-height: 1.5em
  }
div {
  cursor: pointer
  }
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hi">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://clients.brettcolephotography.com/test/articulate.min.js"></script>
    
        <div id="box">Pick a category. Then click on each word to hear it spoken.</div>
        
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="prev()">prev</button> 
            <button type="button" onclick="next()">next</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div onclick="lone()">Fruits</div>
            <div onclick="ltwo()">Animals</div>
            <div onclick="lthree()">Colors</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is there any JSfiddle or sandbox where the problem can be simulated, your current snippet does not work and throw error.

Comment: hmmm, it is working here, let me put it up on my server, ok, it's here - http://clients.brettcolephotography.com/test

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a design model:

- Have a array , something like const items=[];
- Have another array something like const categories=["fruit","animal"]
- When your page loads fetch the top category from above the array, ex: fruits, then have a render function which will push data into items based upon the category. After the push call the render function again which loads the list item based upon data avilable in the items array.
- attach eventhandler to the new list items rendered through above code.